# Inline listing inside a link inside a table

Tags: tables, hyperref, listings

I would like to include an inline listing (using the `listings` package), inside a link (using the `hyperref` package), inside a table.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \begin{tabular}{c}
     \href{www.x.com}{\lstinline{x=y}}
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

This fails with `pdflatex` with the error

```
    ! Missing { inserted.
<inserted text>
                {
l.8   \end{tabular}
```

How can I produce the desired behavior?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So long as the `\lstinline` doesn't contain unbalanced braces or other special characters, you can use `\lstinline|...|` (where `|` is a character not appearing in the code). Otherwise you can use a box:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}

\begin{tabular}{c}
\href{www.x.com}{\lstinline|x=y|}
\\
\setbox0=\hbox{\lstinline|x=#y|}%
\href{www.x.com}{\box0}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```